# Tool for migration to MYSQL Database

Tags: database, migration

Is there any tool to migrate a SQL Server stored procedure to MySQL?

I have approximately 200 stored procedure in SQL server built in function and other properties like CTE and temp tables etc. I have to convert all those stored procedures to MYSQL

Please suggest any tool if available.

Thanks and regards..

Answer (score 1):

At this [link](http://www.mysql.fr/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-migrating-from-sql-server-to-mysql/) (you have to have an oracle account) they explain you in details how to do the migration.

Fill the informations required and you can download a PDF with all the explanations.